# The training accuracy dropped over the epochs

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a CNN network using CIFAR-10 dataset but I'm facing an unusual thing. The training accuracy has dropped after epoch number 25 as it is shown in the learning curve. Is that usual? if it is how can we interpret this?

[image]

Comment: Most likely your learning rate is too large or doesn't decrease fast enough over time. You're overshooting the minimum of the loss function.

Comment: @AlexR. could you elaborate overshooting the minimum of the loss function? Thanks

Comment: See: http://cs231n.github.io/assets/nn3/learningrates.jpeg
and
https://sebastianraschka.com/images/blog/2015/singlelayer_neural_networks_files/perceptron_learning_rate.png